# express appending trailing slash to my static files

Tags: express

Somehow I got my express app into a broken state where it's appending a trailing slash to all static file requests. I'm using this:

```
app.use([/^\/api*/, '/*'], express.static(path.resolve('./public/dist'), { maxAge: 86400000 }));
```

Whenever a request comes in for a found resource (e.g. JS file), express appends a slash, causing browser to think it's an HTML file.